# No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow' error even after installing Visual C++ and MSVCP140.dll

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, speech-recognition

I'm trying to run the simple speech recognition network example of Tensorflow:

```
python tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py
```

But I keep getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
>       fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
>       raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
>   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 66, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
>       import _pywrap_tensorflow
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "tensorflow/examples/speech_commands/train.py", line 79, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 72, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
>       fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
>       raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
>   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 66, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\DELL 7000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
>       import _pywrap_tensorflow
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Most of the solutions I found told me to reinstall visual c++ or to manually add MSVCP140.dll to the path. But neither of these solve my problem.

The github page it tells me to refer returns a 404.

I'm on python 3.7.2 and tensorflow 1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You should change versions of either Python or Tensorflow, as these 2 versions you are using are not compatible. You could downgrade to Python3.6 or try Tensorflow>=1.13.1 which supports Python 3.7.